# Django static file directory not being ignored

Tags: django, configuration

I am getting familiar with Django and wondering if someone seasoned could help me out. I have my project like this:

```
panel
-> media
-> static
-> templates
-> users
```

with the additional python files. Media and Static are just that, media and static folders, and my template folder is templates. Users is an app. I have my static root pointed to that static folder and my media root pointed to the media folder, however it still tries to treat them as if they were Django apps and so it doesn't ignore them. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: "however it still tries to treat them as if they were Django apps and so it doesn't ignore them". Who is doing that?

Comment: I'm just not sure what "it tries to treat them as apps" means.

Comment: Django will not consider something an app unless you list it in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Comment: My file will not show publically, I am getting a page not found.

Comment: Please post info in urls.py and the URL you're trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

The django development server will not serve static files unless you write code explicitly to do so.  It's not like apache which by default maps URLs to the filesystem.  All requests must go through `urls.py`.

Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: I used that and I am still getting a 404. My settings are:
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/darren/Django/panel/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: Is django.contrib.staticfiles in your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Weird guys, I moved my static files root to STATICFILES_DIRS and it worked.

Comment: If you are in development mode, make sure following settings

STATIC_URL = "static/"
Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your INSTALLED_APPS.
DEBUG = True 

If you are on production server, make sure your apache/nginx is set properly to server your static files 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/